# Plone Registry Issues: Data disappears after restart and permission issue

Tags: plone

*Running Plone 5.0.0*

**1.  Registry Permission Issues**

I'm doing something like the following for the retrieval:

```
registry = getUtility(IRegistry)
building_hours = registry['polklibrary.hours.cache']
return building_hours
```

Works great when logged in but for an anonymous user it return a None type.  Doesn't throw an error.  I'm kind of lost why?  It might be because of #2.

**2. The data in the registry is lost after I restart plone.**

The hours type in #1 is a Dict type (which is allowed in the registry).  However it is lost on a restart.

I've checked all these resources with no luck:
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/plone.registry
https://github.com/plone/plone.app.registry

(BTW, the Registry is awesome!)

Edit:

What saves the data:
https://github.com/polklibrary/polklibrary.google.hours/blob/master/polklibrary.google.hours/src/polklibrary/google/hours/browser/cron.py

What reads the data:
https://github.com/polklibrary/polklibrary.google.hours/blob/master/polklibrary.google.hours/src/polklibrary/google/hours/browser/feeds.py

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because dictionaries are not persistent.  The Zope database does not realise that you have made a change to the dictionary.  You need to give it a hint.  The easiest way to do that, is to explicitly save the whole dictionary, in your case like this:

```
registry['polklibrary.google.hours.cache'] = registry['polklibrary.google.hours.cache']
```